# How to take year from input

Tags: java

I got this code :

```
public class NewClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Input your place and date birth : ");
        String birth = in.nextLine();
    }
}
```

And I will input `Malang, 22 May 1997`. The problem how to change my input from string to int, and how to take only the year. So I can use for

```
if (2015 - year < 20 ) {
    System.out.println ("You are teen");
}
```

Comment: You can split the String, using the split method, and after that, split it again.

Comment: First tell the user to enter dob in a specific date format.. Then use `yourString.replaceAll(".*\\s(\\d{4})$","$1")` to extract only the year and parse it as an int using `Integer.parseInt()`

Comment: Either you do it one- by one ( ask for place, ask for year, ask for month...) or parse your input with a regex or the like

Comment: I don't get it in yourString.replaceAll. I only know Integer.parseInt

Comment: @dalladirosa If you look at my answer it shows you how to separate the year from the rest of the string and then it shows you how to compare it to the current year and how to tell if it is less than 20

Comment: @dalladirosa If my answer satisfies you would you mind clicking on the tick next to my answer. I would appreciate it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be better if you'll split the "input" into two.
and then tell the user to enter his/her birthday in this format (Month Day, Year). The comma is important because after the comma the year follows.

```
int year = 0;
String place = "";
Scanner place_in = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Enter place of Birth : ");
place = place_in.nextLine();
String bday = "";
Scanner bday_in = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Enter Birthday (Month Day,Year): ");
bday = bday_in.nextLine();

for(int i=0;i<bday.length();i++) {
    if(bday.charAt(i)==','){
      year = Integer.parseInt(Character.toString(bday.charAt(i+2))+Character.toString(bday.charAt(i+3))+Character.toString(bday.charAt(i+4))+Character.toString(bday.charAt(i+5)));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually it depends on what format will have your input. If format will be hardcoded (`<name>`, `<month>` `<day>` `<year>`) you can just split the given string by space symbol and take the last item and try to convert it to a Number.

Comment: Okay, Forget about (,)..How to take the last item and convert it?

Comment: My code might be incorrect in words but the meaning should be clear. Integer.parseInt("string".split(" ") [4])

Comment: Can you give me the correct code? Because i try it, it give me error

Answer (score 0):

This code will do what you want. First it takes the input `Malang, 22 May 1997` and splits it at the `,` into an array. Then it takes the second index of the array and formates it into a date. After it saves the year in a string. The next function gets the current year and subtracts the year you entered from the current year. Finally it compares it to 20 and prints out `You are teen` if `i` is less than 20.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class YearExtract
{
    String originalString;
    String dateOfBirth;
    String yearOfBirth;
    String currentYear;

    public void setDateOfBirth()
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Input your place and date birth : ");
        String originalString = in.nextLine();

        String[] splitString = originalString.split(",");
        dateOfBirth = splitString[1];
        try
        {
            SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMMM yyyy");
            Date date = format.parse(dateOfBirth);
            SimpleDateFormat format2 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy");
            yearOfBirth = format2.format(date);
            System.out.println(yearOfBirth);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {

        }
    }

    public void areYouTeenager()
    {
        Date now = new Date();
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy");
        currentYear = format.format(now);

        int i = Integer.parseInt(currentYear) - Integer.parseInt(yearOfBirth);

        if(i<20)
        {
            System.out.println ("You are teen");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        YearExtract yE = new YearExtract();
        yE.setDateOfBirth();
        yE.areYouTeenager();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if format of String input remains same then below will give you year part as int value,

```
String[] strArray=birth.split(",");
int year = Integer.valueOf(strArray[1].trim().split(" ")[2]).intValue();
```

This code fails if you change input String format.